# Opening a folder using python code

Tags: python

I need to create a python program which is saves as a shortcut ,which displays many options like camera , flash on and off and opening a folder button, ive did everything but opening a folder or a directory  using python im unaware of it ,ive tried os.path but it didnt work , if anyone knows it please help , thanks

Comment: This is not a Pi specific question, it is a general Python question.

Comment: @joan  Yeah actually im doing it in rasberry pi.

Comment: That is irrelevant, you could be doing it on any Python platform, and the solution would be exactly the same.  That is what is meant by not Pi specific.

Comment: @joan Nope , for example there is an option for opening folder using file explorer in windows explorer(path) , im Asking  the same for rasberry pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Solved it

```
webbrowser.open(path)
```

opens the folder using the file explorer .